# C++ Tic Tac Toe - Problems detecting Tie

Tags: c++, arrays

The title kind of says it all. I'm not sure exactly why the Tic Tac Toe program is not detecting a tie. I've attached the main function, additional functions, etc.. I'm not sure what im doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

string displayBoard(string board[9]);   // displays tic tac toe board
bool isGameOver(string board[9]);       // checks if game is over
void displayGameWelcome();              // displays welcome message

int main()
{
string board[9];          // tic tac toe, top row 0 thru 2, middle row 3 thru 5, bottom row 6 thru 8
int position = 0;         // player's position
bool gameOver = false;    // flag variable to mark end of the game
bool validMove = false;   // determines if move is valid or not

displayGameWelcome();

// initializing board with blank spaces
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    board[i] = " ";
}

while (!gameOver)
{
    // player #1's turn **************************
    validMove = false;


    while (!validMove)
    {
        cout << "Enter your position: ";
        cin >> position;

        if (position >= 0 && position <= 8 && board[position] == " ")
        {
            validMove = true;
            board[position] = "x";      // placing x in desired board location
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "That position is already occupied." << endl;
            cout << displayBoard(board) << endl;
        }

    }

    cout << displayBoard(board) << endl;

    if (isGameOver(board))
    {
        gameOver = true;
    }

    // player #2's turn **********************************
    validMove = false;

    while (!validMove)
    {
        cout << "Enter your position: ";
        cin >> position;

        if (position >= 0 && position <= 8 && board[position] == " ")
        {
            validMove = true;
            board[position] = "o";      // placing o in desired board position
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "That position is already occupied." << endl;
            cout << displayBoard(board) << endl;
        }

    }

    cout << displayBoard(board) << endl;

    if (isGameOver(board))
    {
        gameOver = true;
    }

}// end of validMove while loop

system("pause");
return 0;
}// end of main

// ************************** functions *************************

void displayGameWelcome()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe v3.2" << endl;\
    cout << "by Brett Singley & Nick Canarelli" << endl;
    cout << "****************************\n\n\n";
}// end of displayGameWelcome

// checks if game is over
bool isGameOver(string board[9])
{

if (board[0] == "x" && board[1] == "x" && board[2] == "x")
{
    cout << endl << "The game is over - x wins" << endl;
    return true;
}
else if (board[0] == "o" && board[1] == "o" && board[2] == "o")
{
    cout << endl << "The game is over - o wins" << endl;
    return true;
}
else if (board[3]=="x" && board[4]=="x" && board[5]=="x")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - X wins" <<endl;
}
else if (board[3]=="o" && board[4]=="o" && board[5]=="o")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - o wins" <<endl;
}
else if (board[0]=="x" && board[3]=="x" && board[6]=="x")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - X wins" <<endl;

}
else if (board[0]=="o" && board[3]=="o" && board[6]=="o")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - o wins" <<endl;
}
else if (board[6]=="x" && board[7]=="x" && board[8]=="x")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - X wins" <<endl;
}
else if (board[6]=="o" && board[7]=="o" && board[8]=="o")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - O wins" <<endl;
}
else if (board[1]=="x" && board[4]=="x" && board[7]=="x")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - X wins" <<endl;

}
else if (board[1]=="o" && board[4]=="o" && board[7]=="o")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - O wins" <<endl;
}
else if (board[2]=="x" && board[5]=="x" && board[8]=="x")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - X wins" <<endl;
}
else if (board[2]=="o" && board[5]=="o" && board[8]=="o")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - o wins" <<endl;
}
else if (board[0]=="x" && board[4]=="x" && board[8]=="x")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - X wins" << endl; 
}
else if (board[0]=="o" && board[4]=="o" && board[8]=="o")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - o wins" <<endl;
}
else if (board[2]=="x" && board[4]=="x" && board[6]=="x")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - X wins" <<endl;
}
else if (board[2]=="o" && board[4]=="o" && board[6]=="o")
{
    cout <<endl << "The game is over - o wins" <<endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "WOAH!!!!! Tie Game" <<endl;
}


// more to do here (don't forget to check for draw)

return false;
}// end of isGameOver

// displays tic tac toe board in the format
// |0 1 2|
// |3 4 5|
// |6 7 8|
string displayBoard(string board[9])
{
string str = "";

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{

    if (i == 0)
    {
        str = str  + "|" + board[i];
    }
    else if (i == 2 || i == 5)
    {
        str = str + board[i] + "|\n|";
    } 
    else if (i == 8)
    {
        str = str +  board[i] + "|\n";
    } 
    else
    {
        str = str + board[i];
    }

}

return str;
}// end of displayBoard
```

Comment: well, you may want to finish up that isGameOver function first or post your newest code. returns missing

Comment: would you mind steering me in the right direction? i'm not sure what's missing

Comment: You're not returning true in all cases when the game is finished...

Comment: You should create a function to make a move, where you give as a parameter who is the player to move, avoiding repeated code...

Comment: @nackolous sorry, since you had the `return true` in a couple cases I assumed you just posted the wrong code. Your function returns TRUE if game is over, and FALSE if not, correct? However, your tie games and some win cases do not have a `return true`. They return false based on the code you gave. I bet you just forgot them when you came back to the function. happens to the best of us

Comment: also, an incomplete game will result in a TIE due to the else() capturing all other possibilities, which is probably not what you want

Comment: Your can simplify your program by using `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify checking for a winner by using `for` loops and realizing that the value in the three spaces are equal (to something other than the initial value).  Also, since there are 3 rows and 3 columns, the rows and columns can be checked inside the same `for` loop:

```
const char initial_value = ' ';
const unsigned int max_rows_or_columns = 3;
bool Is_Game_Over(int board[9], char& winner)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < max_rows_or_columns; ++i)
    {
        // Check the row
        if (   (board[(i * 3) + 0] == board[(i * 3) + 1])
            && (board[(i * 3) + 1) == board[(i * 3) + 2]))
        {
           // By transitive property, board[(i * 3) + 0] == board[(i * 3) + 2]
           winner = board[(i * 3) + 0];
           if (winner != initial_value)
           {
               break;
           }
        }
        else // Check the columns
        {
            if (   (board[(0 * 3) + i] == board[(1 * 3) + i])  
                && (board[(1 * 3) + i] == board[(2 * 3) + i]))
            {
                winner = board[(0 * 3) + i];
                if (winner != initial_value)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    bool winner_found = true;
    if (i >= max_rows_or_columns)
    {
        winner_found = false;
    }
    return winner_found;
}
```

The checking of the diagonals is left as an exercise for the reader.